# Issues accessing HTTPS Webservices through PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, web-services, ssl, plsql, oracle11g

I access to a HTTPS webservice through **SYS.UTL_HTTP** PL/SQL package.

The Webservice Certificate has just been expired.

I renewed the certificate but I could not access to the webservice through PL/SQL

When I call for the webservice I get this error message:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
```

Despite the certificate is valide, I got the **Certificate validation failure** error!

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to update the certificate at BD server level. Following the steps to do it:

```
1. Depose the new certificate at the Wallet directory: /app/wallet/certif in my case.
2. Chmod 750 on the certificate files
3. Connect to the database instance with an admin user
4. Go to the directory /app/wallet/certif
5. Import the certificate with the following commands line:
    => a.   orapki wallet add -wallet /appli/wallet -trusted_cert -cert "CERTIF_NAME-cert.pem" –pwd XXXXXXX
```